# DataTable Clone

Tags: datatable

ds = (DataSet)Session["Details"];
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

```
DataTable temp = dt.Clone();
dt.Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].Select("ID =" + ID));
```

Error message:`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRow' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Data.DataRow> in Date Column.  Expected type is DateTime.`

can anybody help me please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ImportRow** is designed for this kind of scenarios only, so check it out.  I have used it manytimes for such requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a fault in the overloads. If you were working in VB, I would tell you to use the `row:=ds.Tables[0].Select("ID =" + ID)` notation in the parameters, but I don't think `C#` has this.

I think the `Add` function assumes you're feeding it the array of values for the new row, instead of a datarow itself.